# Keys seem to be ignored in Lockbox encryption/decryption

Tags: delphi, encryption, lockbox

I'm getting started with TurboPower Lockbox for Delphi. Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation, so I'm using basic functionality to try and find out how Lockbox works. In the example below I have a button for encrypting plaintext to ciphertext, and one for decrypting the ciphertext back to plaintext. This seems to work, but note that I've used different encryption and decryption keys. (The generated ciphertext is also always the same, no matter what the key/passphrase is.)
So apparently I'm either using the SetKey method wrong, or I'm missing a step.

```
procedure TMainForm.BtnEncryptClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TLbRijndael.Create(nil) do
  try
    SetKey('Key1');
    EdtEncrypted.Text := EncryptString(EdtPlainText.Text);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.BtnDecryptClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TLbRijndael.Create(nil) do
  try
    SetKey('Key2');
    EdtDecrypted.Text := DecryptString(EdtEncrypted.Text);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

What's wrong/missing in this code?

---

**Edit**
Extra credit for a link to Lockbox' documentation :-)

Comment: (https://web.archive.org/web/20010628215156/http://www.turbopower.com/products/lockbox/asymmetric/default.asp) Sadly, online documentation was something for the future way back in 1998.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Freddie. I've used other TurboPower software at the time (1998), and I found the documentation (PDF document) of very good quality. I was hoping that the documentation (PDF) would have been released together with the software when TurboPower abandoned it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a very old version of Lockbox (Lockbox2).  You can find docs for that version at [Turbo Power Lockbox Files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/files/TurboPower%20LockBox/LockBox%20version%202/2.07/)

The problem with your code is that you've never set the **KeySize**, and by default the **KeySize** length in bytes is 0 (due to what appears to be a bug in the **TLbRijndael** constructor and destructor) . That being the case, your keys match because what you pass to **SetKey()** is, in effect, ignored. Using the debugger and tracing into the **SetKey()** method would have shown you that the move() statement was moving zero bytes.

However.... You should not call **SetKey()** directly unless you make sure that value passed to **SetKey()** is *key-sized* bytes long.  Instead your should call the **GenerateKey()** method, which will take a string and generate the proper sized key.

```
procedure TMainForm.BtnEncryptClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TLbRijndael.Create(nil) do
  try
    KeySize := ks128;
    GenerateKey('Key1');
    EdtEncrypted.Text := EncryptString(EdtPlainText.Text);
  finally
    Free;
    end;
end;
```